# Windows script auto-update replacing current executable with exec?

Tags: windows, perl, exec, cpan, strawberry-perl

I'm trying to build a quick auto-updater in Perl Windows. I've noticed that when I call `cpanp` to install the update of the package it fails to install a new version of the script because the script is currently running. I'm calling `cpanp` with `CORE::system()` currently. If I called `cpanp` with `exec()` would that release the executable for replacement? Or, does Windows keep it tied up even though execution has been turned over entirely to `cpanp`?

Currently, my process flow looks something like this,

1. Download [META.yml](http://dmclientsoftware.dealermade.com/ftp360/META.yml) from server
2. Parse out the version of META.yml
3. Compare against the current `$VERSION`

   - If the current version is lower, generate a version string using the data in META.yml

     1. Generate a  URL to package using the host/path fo META.yml and the version/data information
     2. Inform user of update
     3. Spawn `cpanp` to run update with URL.
   - If the current version is the same

     1. Do nothing

Would `system()` behave differently than `exec()` on Win32 with regard to replacement of the executable? On Linux it works as designed.

Comment: Are you talking about the **Perl** Executable?

Answer (score 1):

I just tested it. `exec` works as it should on both Linux and Win32. [See this page for portability info on Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#exec).